# AT42QT2160 capacitive touch controller inverted Cs voltage - no touch detected

Tags: microchip, atmel, capacitive, qtouch

I'm trying to make my own development board for the AT42QT2160 Touch controller, since the original one was discontinued. I've designed the PCB with 8 buttons and a slider consisting of 8 sections. It's a two-layer slider/button, which means the X-line is on the one side of the PCB, and the Y-line is on the other. (See more [here](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/doc10752.pdf), page 50). With a scope, I see my touches just fine, but the IC doesn't detect any.

When I measure the X pulses with a coin as specified in the datasheet, I get the correct pulses. However, when I measure the Y voltages, the voltage makes a positive incline instead of the negative decline. I believe that is the reason I can not read any touches. What did I do wrong?

I've already specified the number of keys as well as resolution via I2C. 
Microchip support suggested adding a front panel, but I have already tried that. It only affects the sensitivity, based on the thickness.

My measurement of the Cs voltage:

[image]

The [datasheet's](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-9502-AT42-QTouch-BSW-AT42QT2160_Datasheet.pdf) Cs voltage measurement:

[image]

The schematics: 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, so it was a true noob mistake. I measured on the wrong side of the Cs capacitor... When I measure on the side closest to the uC, I get the correct readouts.

[image]